# Weighted quadratic mean inequality

Tags: inequality, average, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

It is very well-known that given positive real numbers $a,b$, then
$$
\dfrac{a+b}{2} \le \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}} ,
$$
and equality holds if and only if $a=b$.

Is there an analogous "weighted" inequality? That is, if $0<\lambda<1$  and $\mu=1-\lambda$, can we say that for every positive real numbers $a,b$,
$$
\lambda\cdot a + \mu\cdot b \le \sqrt{\lambda\cdot a^2 + \mu\cdot b^2} ,
$$
and that equality holds if and only if $a=b$?
If so, does this result have a name?

Comment: Your last inequality is called AM GM inequality with $(a_1,a_2) = (\sqrt{\lambda}, \sqrt{\mu})$ and $(b_1,b_2) = (\sqrt{\lambda}a, \sqrt{\mu}b)$:   $$(a_1b_1 +a_2b_2)^2 \le (a_1^2+a_2^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2)$$

Comment: That is certainly true.

Comment: The inequality name is rather "Cauchy–Schwarz inequality"

Comment: Alternatively, the statement you have written is just the strict convexity of $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$.